# Add new media type to Mapping2JacksonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, jackson, converters, mime-types

I am trying to add a new type to the jackson converter, its a custom type but its really just json and the standard object mapper should be ok to convert it to java objects.

I am trying the following:

```
@Bean
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
{
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    MediaType fhir = new MediaType("application", "json+fhir");

    List<MediaType> jacksonTypes = new ArrayList<>(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());

    jacksonTypes.add(fhir);

    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jacksonTypes);

    return converter;
}
```

When I debug the application on start up and look at the list of supported types I can see the fhir media type in there but I still get the same error:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class MyClass] and content type [application/json+fhir]
```

I am looking for some help to get the message converter to work with this custom type.

Thanks

** Edit - I fixed this using Stanislavs answer below:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    messageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    return restTemplate;
}  

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
{
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    MediaType fhir = new MediaType("application", "json+fhir");

    List<MediaType> jacksonTypes = new ArrayList<>(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());

    jacksonTypes.add(fhir);

    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jacksonTypes);

    return converter;
}
```

Comment: *Note*: if the the format's syntax is `json` and this `fhir` represents the semantics, its media type should be `application/hfir+json`, which is supported by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` out-of-the-box (because it supports `application/*+json` by default).

Comment: I can see that supported type when I debug the arraylist of types. So basically it should just work ok without me needing to do anything?

Comment: yes. but OFC, you'll need to register the converter too (@StanislavL raises a valid point).

Comment: I am using springboot and it works out of the box without any configuration for standard json as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess your converter is not registered properly. I think Jackson separately add the converter and your bean is just ignored.

See [the example](http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.com.by/2015/02/writing-custom-http-message-converter.html)

Just create your converter class extending `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` 
 and register it like this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
      <bean class="com.example.MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Despite what I have read about spring boot you are completely correct, I debugged all the message converters the rest template knows about and it is indeed wired with some other instance of the jackson converter. Thanks